# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, sql, laravel, update

Делаю на Laravel небольшой тестовый инет магаз. Пытался реализовать редактирование профиля пользователя. Вот столько там есть полей:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->string('img')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Но я пытаюсь изменить только 3 из них, а ругается, что у других нет дефолтного значения, а почему оно другие поля вообще трогает? Или это я что то не так делаю?

```
public function user_edit(Request $request, User $user){

      $user->name = $request->name?$request->name:Auth::user()->name;
      $user->email = $request->email?$request->email:Auth::user()->email;
      $user->phone = $request->phone?$request->phone:(Auth::user()->phone?Auth::user()->phone:NULL);
      $user->save();

      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: Сможете по логу запросов подтвердить, что пытаетесь _изменить_ данные, а не сделать insert?

Comment: Точно! Я новое значение вставлял.

Comment: Неважно, сколько полей задаётся - при INSERT создаётся запись. Целая, а не огрызок, т.е. запись содержит ВСЕ поля структуры. Если какому-то полю не присваивается значение явно - ему присваивается значение, определённое в структуре как дефолтное. Если дефолтное значение не указано - присваивается NULL. Если поле определено как NOT NULL - попытка вставки приводит к ошибке.

Comment: Да, я понял, спасибо! Только изучаю Laravel, я не знал что метод save() только создает новую запись(думал обновляет если уже есть, если нет, то добавляет), оказывается там есть update() для обновления поля.

Answer (score 0):

Причина в том, что я для обновления полей использовал метод, который добавляет новую запись (если я правильно понял), а не обновляет текущую.

Я делал так:

`$user->save();`

А нужно так:

`$user->update();`

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/562700)

Comment: Это решение моего вопроса. Никто отдельным комментарием не написал, поэтому я сам решил это сделать. Я отредактировал, теперь больше на ответ похоже.